# msxml3.dll error "80070005' access denied on webmatrix .asp document on XMLdocument.Save()

Tags: xml, asp-classic

This is the code that doesn't work:

```
<%
    set xmlSave=Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
        xmlSave.async=false
        xmlSave.loadXML("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?><news></news>")
        xmlSave.Save("test.xml")
%>
```

Do I have to give permissions somewhere? Should this work on a server other than webmatrix?

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing this:

```
 xmlSave.Save Server.MapPath("test.xml")
```

this will create the `test.xml` file in the same physical folder that the executing ASP page is found in.